# Ten-hour layover in Narita Japan Airport. Can I leave the airport?

Tags: visas, layovers, tokyo, nrt, swedish-citizens

I'm arriving in Narita airport on December 16 at 09:25 AM. I am a Swedish citizen.

We have a layover of 10 hours. Can we leave the airport within those hours? 
Do we need a visa? And how long does it take to go to Tokyo city? Many questions, but I would be so glad if someone could help me out.

Comment: What citizenship(s) do you hold?

Comment: Have you checked the timetable for the Narita Express?

Comment: My citizenship is Sweden! 
No i haven't checked the timetable, where do I do that?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Narita+express+timetable

Answer (score 1):

As a Swedish citizen, [you may enter Japan without a visa for up to 90 days](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=SE&DE=NRT&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX); proof of an onward or return ticket may be required.

You could leave the airport during your layover. After passing through immigration, you can proceed to [the train](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/access/#section-1), which will be the fastest route to central Tokyo (there is also bus service, taxis, etc...). Both the [Narita Express](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/nex/) and the [Skyliner](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/us/index.php) serve the airport. You'd likely want the Narita Express, but your exact route would depend on where you're going. [A round-trip ticket](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/nex_round.html) is available for 4,000 yen, and the trip from Narita to Tokyo Station takes roughly 53 minutes, running every half hour. Consult [the timetables](https://www.eki-net.com/pc/jreast-shinkansen-reservation/English/wb/common/timetable/index.html) for exact times. There are also packages including public transit tickets available.

Answer (score 1):

The old city of Narita is beautiful. There is an exquisite Buddhist monastery, tiny winding streets, quaint old shops.  Not, as they say, to be missed.